# How can I make individual items on the nav bar stretch?

Tags: html, css

In my navagation bar, I want only hovered on elements to stretch out and change color, but it seems the whole navagation bar stretches. I've tried changing what must be hovered on to trigger the animation, but nothing seems to be working. Can you identify and correct my error?

```css
@keyframes mouse {
  0% {
    background-color: #35B1C2;
    height: 40px
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #2F9EBD;
    height: 60px
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #35B1C2;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: mouse;
}

li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `overflow:hidden` and add

```
overflow:visible;
height:45px; /* The height of your navbar */
```

to your `ul` element.

Comment: Thanks! I now see my mistake :P. I originally made the navbar without the intention of the stretch animation, so i forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul, li a:hover {
   font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: When using your code directly, it works, but when replacing the rule set with my rule set, right when the page loads it trigers the animation (for the whole nav bar) and then the nav bar becomes weird ( links don't higlight when hovered over). I think this has to do with a problem in the animation itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no error in your code. What happens is that the `ul` box contains the `li` boxes. So, when you hover on a `li` box and the `li` box's height increases from 40px to 60px, the `ul` box that is containing that box also stretches out because it needs to contain the `li` box.

So, you just need to work around that issue. I'd suggest not using the `ul` box at all, but that's just something I think is more efficient because you realize you don't actually really need it (you'd still need to contain the navigation bar inside of a box, maybe a `div` or `header`).

Answer (score 0):

You have not set a nav bar heigh. So when the li height change on hover, the navbar will adjust its height to fit the content. Instead of going with animation, I would do this with a simple transition. Add a min-height to the navbar and apply a transition property to the ul tag. Also apply an overflow:visible on hover

See snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #35B1C2;
      min-height: 50px;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li :hover {
      background-color: #2F9EBD;
      height: 60px;
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    
    ul:hover {
      overflow: visible;
    }
    
    li {
      border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    
    li:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```